# How to emit Ctrl-C (keyboard interrupt) in Eclipse console?

Tags: eclipse

I want to terminate some program with **use Ctrl-C in Eclipse console** - how can I emit such keys stroke?

I need to test on KeyboardInterrupt exception code in debug mode with PyDev but it not matter if I will send Ctrl-C it will works.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423405/stop-a-running-command-in-pydev-console

Answer (score 0):

> How to emit Ctrl-C (keyboard interrupt) in Eclipse console?

You can Try `Ctrl` + `Z`

Comment: Ctrl + Z does not work for me in the eclipse console .. same as Ctrl + C

Answer (score -2):

To change keyboard bindings go to Window > Preferences > General > Keys and find "Terminate" with a red box by its name. Then click the box where it says "Ctrl + F2" and hold Ctrl + C.

Visual Example: http://imageupper.com/g/?S020001004M14616836161626229

Comment: Nope - at least, not for me. The Eclipse "Terminate" doesn't merely send a SIGINT (on \*Nix, or equiv on Win\*), it does something harsher - probably a SIGKILL (or equiv). Thus, it does NOT emulate a Ctrl-C (Break) from the console input; thus, it does NOT trigger a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.  (･᷄ ︵･᷅)