# Stop a running command in PyDev Console

Tags: python, console, pydev, keyboardinterrupt

I use the PyDev console to run long scripts, and often I wish to stop in the middle of a command. In a regular python shell I press ctrl+c and it stops the command with keyboard interrupt. But in PyDev consoles it does a text copy instead.

How do I stop a command in this console without terminating it?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23782505/4016674

Comment: It seems similiar to thread.interrupt_main(), and I hope for a way without using a second python comsole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the scripts from an interactive console with newish PyDev (not sure which version this feature arrived) then you can press the Yellow stop to achieve what you want.

[image: interrupt interactive console]

If you are simply running the script (not via the interactive console) then I recommend a feature request at PyDev. https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/